# Operational Calculus for Homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I watched a [Youtube vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8Rxlc-fGr0) on operational calculus which is really interesting. There is an example on solving Homogeneous ODE which I transcribe below:
$$
\begin{align*}
& y-\frac{dy}{dx}=x^3 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& y-\mathcal{D}y=x^3 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& (1-\mathcal{D})y=x^3 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& (1-\mathcal{D})y=x^3 + 0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& y=(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}x^3+(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& y=(1+\mathcal{D}+\mathcal{D}^2+\mathcal{D}^3+\cdots)x^3+(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& y= x^3+3x^2+6x+6+(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad& y= x^3+3x^2+6x+6+ce^x
\end{align*} 
$$

However I don't understand the last step of the above (on [10:54 of the vedio](https://youtu.be/N8Rxlc-fGr0&t=654)), which is:
$$(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}0=ce^x$$
Could any one help to explain? Many thanks.

---

**Edit 1:** To clarify my question, I understand that it is easy to verify $(1-\mathcal{D})e^x=0$. But let's say I don't want to guess the solution, but would like to follow a similar spirit of the operational calculus, namely using the inverse of the operator. Obviously, below argument doesn't make sense:

$$(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}0=(1+\mathcal{D}+\mathcal{D}^2+\mathcal{D}^3+\cdots)0=ce^x$$

Comment: $(1 - D)^{-1} = 1 + D + D^2 + \cdots$ doesn’t make too much sense. First of all, $1 - D$ isn’t even invertible. Even if it were, $(1 - D)^{-1} = 1 + D + D^2 + \cdots$ only works when $D$, as an operator, has norm smaller than 1, which is not the case here. (Instead, $D$ is unbounded.) However, when fed a polynomial $f$, it just so happens to be the case that $(1 - D)(1 + D + D^2 + \cdots)f = 0$, so you do get a specific solution from this. (This happens because $D^n f = 0$ for large enough $n$.)

Comment: I answered this (ages ago) in the video comments somewhere. I'll find my attempt at an explanation if you'd like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finite value of $x$, let's replace $0$ by a limit with an arbitrary constant $c$:
$$0=c\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{x^m}{m!}$$
Then, non-rigorously and in the spirit of the original YouTube video, we have:
\begin{align*}
    (1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}0
    & = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal{D}^n\right)\left(c\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{x^m}{m!}\right) \\
    & = c\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\mathcal{D}^n x^m}{m!} \\
    & = c\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)}{m!}x^{m-n} \\
    & = c\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{x^{m-n}}{(m-n)!} \\
    & = c\left(\frac{x^\infty}{\infty!}+\frac{x^{\infty-1}}{(\infty-1)!}+\frac{x^{\infty-2}}{(\infty-2)!}+\cdots+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^0}{0!}\right)\\
    & = c\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
    & = ce^{x}
\end{align*}

Comment: What is the rigorous version of this? Looks cursed and resembles a lot the technique used in "Guide to Umbral Calculus" by Licciardi and Dattoli (all umbral calculus looks cursed, so I am kinda not surprised). I thought of writing an explanation from functional analysis perspective, but then realized I don't know functional analysis well enough to do that rigorously. In terms of that book, you declare $x^m/m!$ "an umbral vacuum", and use $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ as evaluation map (instead of $|_{x=0}$).

Answer (score 2):

The explanation I gave in the video comments is

$$y=(1-\mathcal{D})^{-1}(0)\;\;⇔\;\;(1-\mathcal{D})y = 0\;\;⇔\;\;y=\mathcal{D}y$$